# Can't migrate database after scaffold. Section 2.2 Ruby on Rails Tutorial Michael Hartl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, migrate, scaffold, dbmigrate

I'm working through the Hartl ruby on rails tutorial (section 2.2), and I'm having trouble migrating the database. Everything seemed to be working, and then I ran `rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string`  Afterwards I tried to run bundle exec rake db:migrate and got the below error message:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
                                                                                 == 20141125234257 CreateUsers: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:users)
   -> 0.0079s
== 20141125234257 CreateUsers: migrated (0.0080s) =============================

rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:271:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:271:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:271:in `substitute_at'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:97:in `block in substitute_values'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:96:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:96:in `each_with_index'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:96:in `substitute_values'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:56:in `insert'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:521:in `_create_record'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:139:in `_create_record'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:122:in `_create_record'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `block in _create_record'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_create_callbacks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `_create_record'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `_create_record'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:501:in `create_or_update'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_save_callbacks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:142:in `save!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:42:in `save!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:289:in `block in save!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:345:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:218:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:342:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:289:in `save!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:51:in `create!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1015:in `record_version_state_after_migrating'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:985:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1030:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:218:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1030:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:983:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:945:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:941:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:941:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:813:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:791:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:271:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:271:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:271:in `substitute_at'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:97:in `block in substitute_values'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:96:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:96:in `each_with_index'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:96:in `substitute_values'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:56:in `insert'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:521:in `_create_record'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:139:in `_create_record'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:122:in `_create_record'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `block in _create_record'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_create_callbacks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `_create_record'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `_create_record'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:501:in `create_or_update'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_save_callbacks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:142:in `save!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:42:in `save!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:289:in `block in save!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:345:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:218:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:342:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:289:in `save!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:51:in `create!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1015:in `record_version_state_after_migrating'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:985:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1030:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:218:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1030:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:983:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:945:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:941:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:941:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:813:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:791:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I've tried going back to an earlier commit and running everything again but I get the same error message. Are there any more files that I should add that can help with this?

Comment: you should really be using the version of Rails that the tutorial was written for. Otherwise you may encounter all kinds of problems.

Comment: @sevenseacat, this problem occurs using the exact versions of rails and the other gems described in the latest version of RT, 3rd ed.  I just sent a note to the author, Michael Hartl.

Comment: Heard back from Michael who tells me that this issue was corrected on Wednesday, 11/26/2014.  Make sure your Gemfile is from after that and this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I just ran into this as well. This is due to ActiveRecord 4.2.0.beta4 passing a parameter to `Arel::Nodes::BindParam.new`. [Arel 6.0.0 was just released today](https://rubygems.org/gems/arel/versions/6.0.0). In this version, `BindParam` does not accept any parameters in it's initalizer.

ActiveRecord has already fixed this on the `master` branch. Until beta5 is released you'll need to lock your `Gemfile` to `gem 'arel', '6.0.0.beta2'`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm.

Comment: Thank you! fwiw this was also causing an issue with rspec and factory_girl; upgrading to Arel 6.0.0.beta2 fixed it.

Comment: I've done this and it fixed me being unable to run db:migrate - however, my Rails application will still not add a new User as intended. The error reads: 

`ArgumentError in UsersController#create
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`

It seems to have an issue with line 271 of Arel: `Arel::Nodes::BindParam.new '?'`. Any thoughts on this welcome!

Comment: for some reason, i get that error locally - but it works fine when deployed to heroku. not sure what's going on there.

Answer (score 16):

with above solution of changing gemfile.

```
 gem 'arel', '6.0.0.beta2'
```

I got below error message.

```
You have requested:arel = 6.0.0.beta2

The bundle currently has arel locked at 6.0.0.
Try running `bundle update arel`
```

After

```
bundle update arel
```

it worked

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this with

```
rake db:reset
```

After that

```
rake db:migrate
```

worked.