# Compatibility issue? rake db:migrate - wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to run a simple migration and I get this error. I think it's some kind of compatibility error. How can I fix it and how can I avoid compatibility issues in the future?

---

```
Migration: `class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :nume
      t.string :email
      t.string :localitate

      t.timestamps 
    end
  end
end
___________________
```

---

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0.beta4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.0.beta1'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jQuery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.0.0.beta2'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0.0.beta4'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :jruby]

___________
```

---

Error :

wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0
.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_
adapter.rb:271:in `initialize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:271:in`new'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:271:in `substitute_at'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/relation.rb:97:in`block in substitute_values'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/relation.rb:96:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/relation.rb:96:in`each_with_index'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/relation.rb:96:in `substitute_values'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/relation.rb:56:in`insert'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/persistence.rb:521:in `_create_record'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/counter_cache.rb:139:in`_create_record'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:122:in `_create_record'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in`block in _create_record'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/l
ib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/l
ib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in`_run_callbacks'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/l
ib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_create_callbacks'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in`_create_record'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `_create_record'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/persistence.rb:501:in`create_or_update'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/l
ib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in`call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/l
ib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/l
ib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in`_run_save_callbacks'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/persistence.rb:142:in`save!'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/validations.rb:42:in `save!'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in`save!'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/transactions.rb:289:in `block in save!'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/transactions.rb:345:in`block in with_transaction_returning_stat
us'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `tran
saction'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/transactions.rb:218:in`transaction'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/transactions.rb:342:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/transactions.rb:289:in`save!'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/persistence.rb:51:in `create!'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/migration.rb:1015:in`record_version_state_after_migrating'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/migration.rb:985:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/migration.rb:1030:in`block in ddl_transaction'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `bloc
k in transaction'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in`within_new_t
ransaction'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `tran
saction'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/transactions.rb:218:in`transaction'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/migration.rb:1030:in `ddl_transaction'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/migration.rb:983:in`execute_migration_in_transaction'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/migration.rb:945:in `block in migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/migration.rb:941:in`each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/migration.rb:941:in `migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/migration.rb:813:in`up'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/migration.rb:791:in `migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in`migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/li
b/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (require
d)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.r
b:240:in`call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.r
b:240:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.r
b:235:in`each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.r
b:235:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.r
b:179:in`block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.r
b:172:in`invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.r
b:165:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:156:in`invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:112:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:112:in`each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:112:in `block in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:121:in`run_with_threads'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:106:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:84:in`block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:182:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:79:in`run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/bin/rake:33:in
`<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in`load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't migrate database after scaffold. Section 2.2 Ruby on Rails Tutorial Michael Hartl.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139007/cant-migrate-database-after-scaffold-section-2-2-ruby-on-rails-tutorial-michae)

Comment: I did not use scaffold

Comment: Please read careful link, it is a rails bug, i cast to close 3 question like this today.

Comment: Thank you. I was confused. I didn t even have the 'arel' gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is here: [Can't migrate database after scaffold. Section 2.2 Ruby on Rails Tutorial Michael Hartl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139007/cant-migrate-database-after-scaffold-section-2-2-ruby-on-rails-tutorial-michae)

You need to install the arel gem as specified there.