# How do I address Arel incompatibility with Hartl Rails Tutorial (Ch. 2)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org, arel, cloud9-ide

I'm currently working along with Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial (Ch. 2) using Cloud9's IDE. I'm running into an error with `Arel::Nodes::BindParam.new` that is being caused by yesterday's release of Arel 6.0.0. The issue is that `BindParam` no longer accepts parameters, and is being passed one by ActiveRecord. To address this problem earlier on while using `rake db:migrate`, I set a different version of Arel in my Gemfile [as explained by aaron-k here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139007/cant-migrate-database-after-scaffold-section-2-2-ruby-on-rails-tutorial-michae). However, this change has not prevented me from getting the same error while trying to create a 'new user' from the scaffolded Users resource in the tutorial:

```
ArgumentError in UsersController#create
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Extracted source (around line #271):
269   # NOTE: The column param is currently being used by the sqlserver-adapter
270   def substitute_at(column, index)
271     Arel::Nodes::BindParam.new '?'
272   end

  # REFERENTIAL INTEGRITY ====================================

Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/workspace/toy_app

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:30:in `block in create'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:29:in `create'
```

I see no reference to Arel in `users_controller.rb`, and so I am wondering where else I need to require an older version of Arel. Could this be a problem with hosting it through Cloud9 using `rails server`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update to the Arel gem broke migrations in Rails 4 beta. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139007/cant-migrate-database-after-scaffold-section-2-2-ruby-on-rails-tutorial-michae) for details. The tutorial has already been updated with the fix.