# Simple Rails Association causing ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

EDIT: **This is not a dupe** of [Can't migrate after scaffold in Hartl's tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139007/cant-migrate-database-after-scaffold-section-2-2-ruby-on-rails-tutorial-michae)! I have Arel updated in my Gemfile just in case, but it makes no difference. Also, this is POST-migration, the rake finished just fine. However after the rake, when I try to query the association via the console, **that** is when I get the error!

---

I have two models with a simple one-to-many association between them. After adding the second model and raking the db, I opened rails console to test some stuff out, and I get an error every time I try to use the association in a query.

Here are the classes:

```
class Startup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reqs
end

class Req < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :startup
end
```

This is the migration for the Reqs table:

```
class CreateReqs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :reqs do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :desc
      t.integer :sort
      t.references :startup, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the simple test I'm trying to test in the console afterwards:

```
> startup = Startup.first
> startup.reqs              ## Generates ArgumentError
> startup.reqs.build        ## Generates same error
```

And here is the beginning of the error:

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:271:in
>   `initialize'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:271:in

I'm still getting the hang of a lot of the details of RoR, so please hang with me! But from what I thought I knew, this association seems so basic that I have no idea where to start fixing it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that. No scaffolding and I did migrate just fine. It's after migration that this problem occurs when trying to utilize the has_many association.

Comment: [Please read careful, this is a Rails bug.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139007/cant-migrate-database-after-scaffold-section-2-2-ruby-on-rails-tutorial-michae)

Comment: My Gemfile has been locked to the right version of Arel the entire time:

gem 'arel', '6.0.0.beta2'

Still getting the error, any ideas?

Comment: Did you run `bundle update arel` and restart your application server?

Comment: Yes, I did that much earlier on and have restarted the server several times between now and then :/

Comment: What is the output of `bundle show arel`?

Comment: `$ bundle show arel
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/arel-6.0.0.beta2`

Comment: I'm going to call it a night and look at this with fresh eyes in the morning. If you can think of anything else for me to try in the meantime, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: It's quite strange, because the symptoms look exactly like in this other problem, which was fixed by updating `arel` to `6.0.0.beta2`. Anyway, I'm reopening this question.

Comment: just use/install previous Rails version.

Comment: Remove the null:false after timestamps in your migration file, you do not need it. Rails will handle this all alone.

Comment: Someone suggested that before (and then deleted it).Rails generated it automatically in the migration file, which is odd. But I tried, and removing the null:false didn't make a difference. From now on I'll make sure it's not in my migrations though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may have been some sort of fluke or bug in Rails. I tried again this morning and the rails console was still giving me the same error. Then just for kicks I tried adding another model that was the same, just with a different name:

```
class CreateSkills < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :skills do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :desc
      t.integer :sort
      t.references :startup, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

After adding the `has_many skills` to Startup.rb, I went back into Rails console and now BOTH of the associations (`Startup.skills` and `Startup.reqs`) work just fine. Out of curiosity, I did a `db:rollback` and destroyed the `Skill` model and then went back into the console. `Startup.reqs` still works fine even though Skill is not there anymore.

I have no idea why this would make a difference, but wanted to post what worked for me in case someone else runs into a similar issue. Try generating another model to kind of "reset" the db and then you can roll it back and everything may work for you.