# Rails Executing migration ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rake, migrate

I'm having a strange problem executing rake db:migrate

```
== 20141127213559 CreateMovies: migrating =====================================
-- create_table(:movies)
   -> 0.0033s
== 20141127213559 CreateMovies: migrated (0.0034s) ============================

rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What I did was:

```
rails generate model Movie
```

And then edit the migration CreateMovies

```
class CreateMovies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    #drop_table :movies
    create_table :movies do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :rating
      t.text :description
      t.datetime :release_date
      # Add fields that let Rails automatically keep track
      # of when movies are added or modified:
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :movies
  end
end
```

This is the output of executing the command with --trace

```
[fran@arch rottenpotatoes]$ rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
== 20141127213559 CreateMovies: migrating =====================================
-- create_table(:movies)
   -> 0.0039s
== 20141127213559 CreateMovies: migrated (0.0041s) ============================

rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:271:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:271:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:271:in `substitute_at'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:97:in `block in substitute_values'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:96:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:96:in `each_with_index'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:96:in `substitute_values'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:56:in `insert'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:521:in `_create_record'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:139:in `_create_record'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:122:in `_create_record'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `block in _create_record'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_create_callbacks'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `_create_record'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `_create_record'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:501:in `create_or_update'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_save_callbacks'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:142:in `save!'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:42:in `save!'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:289:in `block in save!'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:345:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:218:in `transaction'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:342:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:289:in `save!'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:51:in `create!'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1015:in `record_version_state_after_migrating'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:985:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1030:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:218:in `transaction'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1030:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:983:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:945:in `block in migrate'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:941:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:941:in `migrate'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:813:in `up'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:791:in `migrate'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:156:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `block in top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:121:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `block in run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:182:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/fran/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/fran/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:271:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:271:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:271:in `substitute_at'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:97:in `block in substitute_values'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:96:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:96:in `each_with_index'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:96:in `substitute_values'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:56:in `insert'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:521:in `_create_record'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:139:in `_create_record'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:122:in `_create_record'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `block in _create_record'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_create_callbacks'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `_create_record'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `_create_record'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:501:in `create_or_update'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_save_callbacks'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:142:in `save!'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:42:in `save!'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:289:in `block in save!'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:345:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:218:in `transaction'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:342:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:289:in `save!'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:51:in `create!'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1015:in `record_version_state_after_migrating'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:985:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1030:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:218:in `transaction'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1030:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:983:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:945:in `block in migrate'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:941:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:941:in `migrate'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:813:in `up'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:791:in `migrate'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:156:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `block in top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:121:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `block in run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:182:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/fran/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/fran/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: your migration file looks ok, did you rerun migration with `--trace` again to see full error?

Comment: I just edited the initial thread and put the output with --trace

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Rails 4.2.0.beta4, ActiveRecord will require arel gem. Add the following to your gem file

```
gem 'arel', '6.0.0.beta2'
```

and run

```
bundle install
```

You may get below error message

```
You have requested:arel = 6.0.0.beta2

The bundle currently has arel locked at 6.0.0.
Try running `bundle update arel`
```

then

```
bundle update arel
```

Now you should able to run  migration.

Here you may find similar and explanatory answer: [Can't migrate database after scaffold. Section 2.2 Ruby on Rails Tutorial Michael Hartl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139007/cant-migrate-database-after-scaffold-section-2-2-ruby-on-rails-tutorial-michae)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should execute this after create movies table:

```
generate migration AddFieldsToMovies newfield:type
```

This generates the correct migration, see this:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-tables