# Wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2) with rails 4.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want use gem 'stuff-classifier' in my rails project. Firstly i tested this in new project with rails 4.1.7 and work like i expected.
But when i do the same in my destination project i have problem with ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2). But when i initialize StuffClassifier::Bayes class i gives StuffClassifier::Bayes.new("Music_Classifier")

Below i showed what i maked:

First added to gemfile gem 'stuff-classifier'

Next generated model Classifier with music_classifier text attribute

```
class Classifier < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :music_classifier, StuffClassifier::Bayes
  before_create :initialize_clfr

  private 

  def initialize_clfr
    cls = self.music_classifier = StuffClassifier::Bayes.new("Music_Classifier")

    cls.train(:alternative, "Art Punk Alternative-Rock")
    cls.train(:latin, "Alternativo & Rock Latino ")
  end
end
```

In my db/seeds.rb file i have `Classifier.create!`

Then i try in console `rake db:seed` that gives me this error msg:

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/stuff-classifier-0.5/lib/stuff-classifier/bayes.rb:7:in `initialize'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/coders/yaml_column.rb:24:in `new'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/coders/yaml_column.rb:24:in `load'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/type/serialized.rb:52:in `default_value?'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/type/serialized.rb:16:in `type_cast_from_database'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:94:in `type_cast'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:42:in `original_value'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:37:in `value'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:54:in `changed_in_place_from?'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:74:in `attribute_changed_in_place?'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:149:in `block in changed_in_place'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:148:in `select'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:148:in `changed_in_place'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:141:in `attributes_changed_in_place'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:62:in `changed_attributes'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/dirty.rb:173:in `attribute_changed?'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:115:in `old_attribute_value'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:90:in `write_attribute'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:52:in `block in _create_record'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:49:in `each'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:49:in `_create_record'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:501:in `create_or_update'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_save_callbacks'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:142:in `save!'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save!'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `block in save!'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:347:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:344:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `save!'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:51:in `create!'
/home/pnc/sites/spolisty/db/seeds.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:547:in `load_seed'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:250:in `load_seed'
/home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:180:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

When i try this in rails console i have the same error msg.

```
c = Classifier.new

    Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0)
2.1.3 :001 > c = Classifier.new
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/stuff-classifier-0.5/lib/stuff-classifier/bayes.rb:7:in `initialize'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/coders/yaml_column.rb:24:in `new'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/coders/yaml_column.rb:24:in `load'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/type/serialized.rb:52:in `default_value?'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/type/serialized.rb:16:in `type_cast_from_database'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:94:in `type_cast'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:42:in `original_value'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:37:in `value'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_set.rb:31:in `fetch_value'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:93:in `_read_attribute'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:87:in `read_attribute'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:305:in `attribute_for_inspect'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:443:in `block in inspect'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:441:in `collect'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:441:in `inspect'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'2.1.3 :002 >
```

I try solve this with this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27179138/rails-executing-migration-argumenterror)  on Stack because previously i had rails 4.2.0.rc3 but after upgrate rails to 4.2.0 i still have this problem.

How can i resolve this error or how can i use stuff classifier in other way?

Thx for help.

EDIT:
Content of db/seeds.rb

```
Classifier.create!
```

Comment: What is the content of `seeds.rb`?

Comment: There is simple Classifier.create!

Comment: I can't follow the link to the topic you mention.

Comment: Can you post the database schema for the classifier table?

Comment: show your seeds.rb please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your invocation of `StuffClassifier::Bayes.new`, and everything to do with your attempt to have ActiveRecord serialize it.

All of the code involved is open source, and if you look at your stack trace, you'll see the line that causes the error is:

> .../gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/coders/yaml_column.rb:24:in `new'

This project is freely available to review in your browser:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.0.rc3/activerecord/lib/active_record/coders/yaml_column.rb#L24

The line in question reads:

```
def load(yaml)
  return object_class.new if object_class != Object && yaml.nil?
  # ...
```

As you can see, when your serialized YAML comes back as `nil`, ActiveRecord assumes it can invoke `.new` with no arguments on the class being used for serialization. This makes `StuffClassifier::Bayes`, which does not have a no-argument initializer, unusable as an ActiveRecord serialization class, unless you have a previously serialized value.

You have many ways forward:

- Monkey-path `StuffClassifier::Bayes` so that it can be initialized with no arguments
- Fork the gem on Github, make your modifications and attempt to have them merged into the original repository
- Produce your own class, `StuffclassifierSerializer`, which can serve as an adapter between ActiveRecord and the gem

Comment: Big thanks for your answer. I think the second option could be the best option.