# CH2 Hartl Tutorial Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on the Hartl Ruby on Rails tutorial, Chapter Two (https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app), and working from Cloud9. I have installed the gem using this code:

```
gem install rails -v 4.2.0.beta4
```

I then add the gems to the gemfile.

I then create the new toy app:

```
rails _4.2.0.beta4_ new toy_app
```

I cd to the toy_app.

Then I bundle install:

```
bundle install --without production
```

I then scaffold:

```
rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```

and then I rake:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

But I continually get an error message when I try to access the webpage from Cloud9: 
    https://rails-tutorial-codertodd-3.c9.io/.

The error message usually reads as follows: **Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development**

My friend also tried to do the same operation on a different computer and got the same error message. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

-T

Answer (score 0):

If you follow Michael Hartl's tutorial and have problems with rake db:migrate command (and especially if you are using Cloud9 as development platform) your solution is to update Arel Gem...

just run: `bundle update arel`

If it is not working still, add this line to Gemfile into your development group:

```
gem 'arel', '6.0.0.beta2'
```

then run: `bundle install` and if it is complaining run; `bundle update arel`

migrations should be working now

Found suggestion in this post, so credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/27140014/3251051