# Rails Arel unit test error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, arel

I have the following error:

```
ERROR["test_character_should_be_valid", CharacterTest, 0.214787]
test_character_should_be_valid#CharacterTest (0.21s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `val' for "$1":Arel::Nodes::BindParam
app/models/user.rb:11:in `block in <class:User>'
test/models/character_test.rb:8:in `setup'
```

From the following test: test/models/character_test.rb:

```
    require 'test_helper'

    class CharacterTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

      def setup
        @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", callsign: "example",
                         password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
        @user.save
        @character = @user.character
      end

      test "character should be valid" do
        assert @character.valid?
      end

    end # CharacterTest
```

In the gemfile:

```
gem 'arel', '6.0.0.beta2'
```

character.rb:

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sociable, polymorphic: true
end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one  :character, as: :sociable

  before_validation do
    self.create_character unless character # line 11
  end
  .
  .
end
```

I can't find anything about this particular arel error. My arel gem is 6.0.0.beta2, which seems to fix other problems (as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139007/cant-migrate-database-after-scaffold-section-2-2-ruby-on-rails-tutorial-michae)). Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this isn't an Arel error - it's because the columns sociable_id and sociable_type
weren't defined in the schema. My stupid mistake. Arel was raising an exception because the foreign key was missing. However there is an improved error message at Arel here:
https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/78bd18a90992e3da767cfe492f1bc5d63077da8a