# NoMethodError (undefined method `val' for #<Arel::Nodes::BindParam:0x007f4c99d64cb8>):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, schema, arel

On my local server, I have no issues creating new posts, however, I run into this error when I try to create a new post on my live app hosted on Heroku.

In my research, I found some solutions that haven't worked for me. For example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671756/rails-arel-unit-test-error) mentions updating the schema appropriately-- I would need more help on how the schema should be updated. I also found that [updating the gemfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139007/cant-migrate-database-after-scaffold-section-2-2-ruby-on-rails-tutorial-michae) to include the latest version of the Arel gem worked for some people, but nothing changed for me. My URL is www.humanify.biz/listings and I find the following error in my Heroku logs when I click "New Listing". My git repository is [here](https://github.com/vsquared10/humanifymvp).

Here's my error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `val' for #<Arel::Nodes::BindParam:0x007f4c99d64cb8>):
2015-04-10T23:23:56.722453+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:19:in `new'
2015-04-10T23:23:56.722454+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-04-10T23:23:56.722456+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-04-10T23:23:56.593393+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ListingsController#new as HTML
2015-04-10T23:23:56.604678+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms
2015-04-10T23:23:56.716183+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ListingsController#new as HTML
2015-04-10T23:23:56.721356+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms
```

And here is the relevant error line my app/controllers/listings_controller.rb file:

```
# GET /listings/new
  def new
    @listing = current_user.listings.build
  end
```

Here is the models/listings.rb file:

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "small_Humanify.png"
    # Validate content type
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage/
end
```

Finally, here is my schema.rb file:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150410191114) do

  create_table "listings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
  end

  add_index "listings", ["user_id"], name: "index_listings_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution may be incorrect but it solved my problem:

I changed the "user_id" from an integer to a string.

I assume you are using devise? I went ahead and changed it to a string and it works.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am using devise and since I didn't have any significant data saved in my database, I destroyed the `users` and `listings` table in my terminal and then re-generated them from scratch, ran `run db:migrate` locally and to heroku (`heroku run rake db:migrate`), and it ended up working. `user_id` has to be an integer for my purposes, so unfortunately the other solution wouldn't have worked. Thanks again!