# how to upgrade 'arel' gem in a rails engine, Ryan Bigg's book

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

I tried to add the following link to my gemspec :

```
  s.add_dependency 'arel', '6.0.0.beta2'
```

then when I run bundle I get

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "arel":
  In Gemfile:
    subscribem (>= 0) ruby depends on
      rails (~> 4.2.0) ruby depends on
        activerecord (= 4.2.0) ruby depends on
          arel (~> 6.0) ruby

    subscribem (>= 0) ruby depends on
      arel (6.0.0.beta2)
```

I need to update arel because it's causing some migration errors known [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139007/cant-migrate-database-after-scaffold-section-2-2-ruby-on-rails-tutorial-michae)

Comment: Delete `Gemfile.lock` file, and run `bundle install` again; that should fix the issue.

Comment: nope, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this did the trick :

```
sudo gem install arel -v 6.0.0.beta2
```