# Ruby on Rails: rake db:migrate error after running scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Have a little issue going on, not too sure what I've done but I just created a rails application followed by these commands.

I ran:

```
rails generate scaffold Post heading body:text price:decimal neighborhood external_url timestamp
```

in my terminal followed by:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Next I get an error that reads:

```
    == 20150108012341 CreatePosts: migrating ======================================
    -- create_table(:posts)
       -> 0.0021s
    == 20150108012341 CreatePosts: migrated (0.0022s) =============================

    rake aborted!
    StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

    wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)/Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:271:in `initialize'
    /Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-
...
4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:135:in `migrate'
    /Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    /Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
    Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Migration file:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :heading
      t.text :body
      t.decimal :price
      t.string :neighborhood
      t.string :external_url
      t.string :timestamp

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The scaffold syntax doesnt look right. You probably need types for neighborhood and external_url

Comment: show us the migration file

Comment: Added the migration file @Anthony

Comment: Okay so this is weird because I tried testing this on another app and it seems every time I run rake db:migrate I get the error "rake aborted!..."

Comment: your scaffold works just fine for me.  Your schema doesn't already include a posts table right?

Comment: Scaffold command also works fine for me when running `db:migrate`. I second the need for checking whether there is already a posts table. I also question why you are manually creating a `timestamp` column as that could cause a lot of confusion for someone trying to understand your Post model.

Comment: No it doesn't already include the posts table. I tried dropping tables in the console, recreating then rake db:reset and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the command should be

```
rails generate scaffold Post heading:string body:text price:decimal neighbourhood:string  externalurl:string timestamp:string
```

You should be mentioning the data types for all the fields .

Comment: Still get an error. I even tried to reinstall rails.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my gem file, my rails version was rails 4.2 beta 2. I found the solution here:

[Can't migrate database after scaffold. Section 2.2 Ruby on Rails Tutorial Michael Hartl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139007/cant-migrate-database-after-scaffold-section-2-2-ruby-on-rails-tutorial-michae)

I had to add the `gem arel` and run `bundle update arel` followed by bundle install.