# Can't migrate psql database after scaffold - Cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, scaffolding, dbmigrate, cloud9

I am getting an "wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)" error when trying to run rake db:migrate on my psql database. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139007/cant-migrate-database-after-scaffold-section-2-2-ruby-on-rails-tutorial-michae) asker had the same trouble, but locking my Gemfile "to gem 'arel', '6.0.0.beta2'" and using rails version 4.2.0.beta4 hasn't fixed the issue though I am able to bundle and am absolutely using these versions. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is the full trace

```
rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
== 20161104230329 Createmytable: migrating ==================================
-- create_table(:mytable)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
/home/ubuntu/workspace/mydb_api/db/migrate/20161104230329_create_mytable.rb:4:in `block in change'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:199:in `create_table'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:655:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:625:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:625:in `say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:645:in `method_missing'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/mydb_api/db/migrate/20161104230329_create_mytable.rb:3:in `change'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:599:in `exec_migration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:583:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:582:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:581:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:758:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:984:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1030:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:218:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1030:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:983:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:945:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:941:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:941:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:813:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:791:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:173:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
/home/ubuntu/workspace/mydb_api/db/migrate/20161104230329_create_mytable.rb:4:in `block in change'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:199:in `create_table'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:655:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:625:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:625:in `say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:645:in `method_missing'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/mydb_api/db/migrate/20161104230329_create_mytable.rb:3:in `change'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:599:in `exec_migration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:583:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:582:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:581:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:758:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:984:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1030:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:218:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1030:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:983:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:945:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:941:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:941:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:813:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:791:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:173:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Here is the file 20161104230329_create_mytable.rb

```
class CreateTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :mytable do |t|
      t.name :string
      t.param1 :integer
      t.param2 :integer
      t.param3 :integer

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: what does this file `20161104230329_create_mytable.rb` look like?

Comment: class CreateTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
  create_table :mytable do |t|
    t.name :string
    t.param1 :integer
    t.param2 :integer
    t.param3 :integer

    t.timestamps null: false
  end
   end
 end

I'm not sure how to format this in a nice way in comments...should I add it to my OP?

Comment: I added the contents of that file to the OP. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the order of the field/field type options of your migration reversed. Should be

```
class CreateTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :mytable do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :param1

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Obviously I'm new to Ruby but I never expected this to be the problem. Cheers!

Comment: Glad to do it. If that fixed your problem please select it as best answer.